# Redirected to Login Page After Successful Authentication with Auth0 in React.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, auth0

I'm currently working on a React.js application where I've implemented authentication using Auth0. The authentication process seems to work correctly, as I can see successful login logs in the Auth0 dashboard. However, after authentication, I'm being redirected back to the login page instead of the expected dashboard.

Here are the key components of my application:

Authentication Provider: I've set up Auth0 authentication using the @auth0/auth0-react library in my React application. The redirectUri is correctly configured in my AuthProvider component.

Routes: I'm using react-router-dom for routing within my React application. I have a /dashboard route that should only be accessible to authenticated users.

AuthHandler: After authentication, I'm using an AuthHandler component to handle the redirect logic. It navigates to /dashboard when the user is authenticated.

After successful authentication, the application redirects me to the root route (/) instead of the intended /dashboard route.

The following console log is never posted after successful login: `console.log("AuthHandler component is rendering");`
Indicating the AuthHandler file is never reached?

**Auth0 URIs:**

Application Login URI: https://127.0.0.1:3000

Allowed Callback URLs: http://localhost:3000/dashboard

Allowed Logout URLs: http://localhost:3000

Allowed Web Origins: http://localhost:3000

```
//App.js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {({ theme }) => (
          <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Router>
              <Navbar />
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
                <Route path="/dash" element={<HorseManagementDashboard />} />
                <Route path="/auth-handler" element={<AuthHandler />} />
                {/* other routes as needed */}
              </Routes>
            </Router>
          </MUIThemeProvider>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
//AppHandler.js
const AuthHandler = () => {
    console.log("AuthHandler component is rendering");
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading, error, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAuth = async () => {
      console.log('AuthHandler State:', { isAuthenticated, isLoading, error });

      if (isLoading) {
        console.log('Authentication Loading...');
        return;
      }

      if (error) {
        console.error('Authentication Error:', error);
        navigate('/'); // redirect to home on error
        return;
      }

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        console.log('Authentication Successful');
        navigate('/dashboard');
        // Optionally get the access token if needed
        try {
          const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
          console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        } catch (getTokenError) {
          console.error('Error getting access token:', getTokenError);
        }
        navigate('/dashboard'); // redirect to dashboard on successful authentication
      } else {
        console.log('Not Authenticated: Redirecting to home');
        navigate('/'); // redirect to home if not authenticated
      }
    };

    handleAuth();
  }, [isAuthenticated, isLoading, error, navigate, getAccessTokenSilently]);

  // Render a loading indicator or any other content as needed
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
};

export default AuthHandler;
```